# c++ open file with ifstream

Tags: c++, file-io, ifstream, wstring

I have been unable to open the file.  The `fb.is_Open()` never returns true.  Only when I hard code the data source in the `fb.open()` it works.

I've tried converting it to a `string`, `char`, and `wstring` with no effect.

**What am I missing?** The correct code would be fantastic but also and explanation.

Trying to open a file with the data source variable:

```
wchar_t dataSource[2048];
DWORD errNum =  GetModuleFileName(NULL, dataSource, sizeof(dataSource)); //get current dir.
ifstream fb;
wcscat_s(dataSource, L".confg");  //adds ".config" to get full data Sournce
fb.open(dataSource, ios::in);
if (fb.is_open())
{
//get information
}
fb.close();
```

Here are some things Ive tried that have not worked:
    wstring x = dataSource;
    x.c_str()

```
char* cnvFileLoc = (char*)malloc(2048);
size_t count;
count = wcstombs_s(&count, cnvFileLoc, 2048, dataSource, 2048);
```

what does work is:
    fb.open(X:\CPP.Lessons\PluralSight\PluralSight.Fundamentals\Debug\PluralSight.Fundamentals.exe.config, ios::in)

Comment: This question started off okay, then it became clear that you'd forgotten to post your testcase. Then you threw in a hugely and broad and subjective _second question_ as an addendum. What.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Also, how do you serve the file contents over HTTP as a static website? Also, the file contains JS code - how can I jit and execute it asynchronously? What are the best practice for designing a web business?

Comment: Your right.  The main issue is why wont the file open.  Only with hard coded values will it work.  The other issue is just where other questions I have.  Ive been researching this with no luck... So far ive tried this:    wstring x = dataSource;
      x.c_str()

Comment: @KerrekSB: Also, how can I build a model city for 30,000 people?

Comment: `.confg` and `.config` are not the same. Is this just a silly typo? Also, your `sizeof(dataSource)` should be `sizeof(dataSource)/sizeof(wchar_t)` .. or something altogether more expressive.

Comment: You have no idea how much time that typo that you spotted in 3 mins sucked up!! Thats exactly what it was a stupid typo in the concatenating.  Also you have me help on the GetModuleFileName.  Your code is more elegant than mine Remy.  Thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your call to `GetModuleFileName()` is wrong.  The last parameter is expressed in **characters**, not in **bytes**, and the return value tells how many **characters** were copied:

```
wchar_t dataSource[2048];
if (GetModuleFileName(NULL, dataSource, 2048) > 0)
{
    ...
}
```

Or:

```
wchar_t dataSource[2048];
if (GetModuleFileName(NULL, dataSource, sizeof(dataSource)/sizeof(dataSource[0])) > 0)
{
    ...
}
```

Or:

```
wchar_t dataSource[2048];
if (GetModuleFileName(NULL, dataSource, _countof(dataSource)) > 0)
{
    ...
}
```

Or:

```
wchar_t dataSource[2048];
if (GetModuleFileName(NULL, dataSource, ARRAYSIZE(dataSource)) > 0)
{
    ...
}
```

That being said, you are appending `.confg` to the end of the full filename.  So, if your application is named `myapp.exe`, you are trying to open `myapp.exe.confg`.  Is that what you really want?

If yes, then make sure the `.confg` file actually exists, and that your app has permission to access it.  `CreateFile()` would offer much more useful error info then `ifstream` does.

Otherwise, assuming the `.confg` file is at least in the same folder as your app, you would have to manually remove the filename portion from the buffer and then substitute in the correct filename.  Have a look at [`PathRemoveFileSpec()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773748.aspx) and [`PathCombine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773571.aspx) for that.  Or, if the file is named `myapp.confg`, look at [`PathRenameExtension()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773749.aspx).

**Update**: I just noticed that your code is appending `.confg`, but your comment says `.config` instead:

```
//wcscat_s(dataSource, L".confg");
wcscat_s(dataSource, L".config");
```

Comment: Gambit, thank you for your quick response. Yes I want to add .config to the end of the GetModuleFileName. The full path of the file is:X:\CPP.Lessons\PluralSight\PluralSight.Fundamentals\Debug\PluralSight.Fundamentals.exe.config.  MSDN said a good exception handle was to check if the response from GetModuleFileName was greater than 0, it might be outdated Ill check on that.

Answer (score 4):

You may have mistyped the file extension: `L".confg"` instead of `L".config"` as stated by the comment in your code.